# Hibernate : hbm2ddl.auto value="update" or "none"

Tags: hibernate, jpa, database-administration

I'm using JPA via Hibernate...

In my persistence.xml I configure hibernate to update the schema as follow :

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

Is it better to let JPA manage our databases or is it better to manage the databases ourselves (manually) ...

```
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
```

The senior developers I know said to me that the second method is better ... because it is a habit the DBA do in all good entreprises .. but I want to have more explanation ... I want to know why the second method is better? why we should not let JPA manage the tables and the relations it self ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good for many reasons, especially in production environments.

- Versioning - you may want to version your database, most people do
  manually by keeping track of db changes, it's good to prepare a revert script for every change. It's important on the version release to have
  a rollback plan in case things go bad.
- Script execution failure - In a database full of data, an alter table which
  adds a non-null column will fail, simply because existing records do
  not have this column. So there are additional steps which are best handled 
  manually.
- Accidental changes. A developer from your team may accidentally
  commit wrongly configured entities and wreak havoc on your schema.

The best is to keep the value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to `validate`, this way entity mappings are validated against database structure, and if there's any mismatch, Hibernate will warn.

Answer (score 3):

Typically it's better to leave the aut ddl to none.
This because you could accidentally cause updates in integration/production environments other than development.
Secondly, the auto generated scripts from hibernate might not be consistent with the conventions used by the dba.